# Value Error in feature selection pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use sklearn.feature_selection on pandas, but getting value error. 
    It is explained step-by-step below.

```
Code:

from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

print (best_features_train_df.columns)

Result:

Index(['cont1', 'cont2', 'cont3', 'cont4', 'cont5', 'cont6', 'cont7', 'cont8',
   'cont9', 'cont10', 'cont11', 'cont12', 'cont13', 'cont14', 'loss'],
  dtype='object')


Code:

array = best_features_train_df.values
X = array[:,0:14] #Selecting all the features from cont1 to cont14
Y = array[:,14] #Selecting the 'loss' which is the class variable
print (X)
print (Y)

Result:

[[ 0.726  0.246  0.188 ...,  0.595  0.822  0.715]
 [ 0.331  0.737  0.593 ...,  0.366  0.611  0.304]
 [ 0.262  0.358  0.484 ...,  0.373  0.196  0.774]
 ..., 
 [ 0.484  0.786  0.792 ...,  0.443  0.339  0.504]
 [ 0.438  0.422  0.299 ...,  0.853  0.655  0.722]
 [ 0.907  0.621  0.441 ...,  0.946  0.811  0.721]]

 [ 2213.18  1283.6   3005.09 ...,  5762.64  1562.87  4751.72]

Code:

test = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=4)
fit = test.fit(X, Y)

Error:

ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([ 2213.18,  1283.6 ,  3005.09,  ...,  5762.64,  1562.87,  4751.72]),)
```

When I checked about the error, it was suggested that Y could be a 2d   list, but its not where am I going wrong? Please suggest me.

Comment: Can you show me the entire error log please ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your 'score_func' in SelectKBest.

It seems that your problem is a regression problem. You cannot use chi2 for a regression problem. You need to use either [f_regression or mutual_info_regression.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#univariate-feature-selection)